# ImageView in ListView gives extra image

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an extra icon while adding ImageView in a ListView as shown below. What is this and how can I remove it?
[image]

In my content it also shows up and when selected it highlights the ImageView shown here
[image]

The xml code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="anaxin.newshellas.Feed"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_feed">

    <ListView
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/feedView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="false" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTop"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTop"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I use a SimpleAdapter with two rows (textTop, TextBot) to populate my listView like this:

```
final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.content_feed,
                new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
                new int[]{R.id.textTop, R.id.textBot}) {
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                return view;
            }
        };
```

And in method to add items this part

```
Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<>(2);
            datum.put("First Line", article.getTop());
            datum.put("Second Line", article.getBot());
            data.add(datum);
```

Comment: Which image is being pointed with `android:src="@drawable/image"`? Have you tried removing this ?

Comment: I think listView item layout is different..This layout is different. Remove or comment ImageView in this layout.

Comment: Do you have an imageview inside the adapter as well? remove the imageview in this layout and keep the one you have inside the adapter

Comment: remove ImageView with id `image`

Comment: @PhanVănLinh textTop is not an imageView. He has to remove ImageView with id "image".

Comment: `android:layout_below="@+id/textTop"` is also conflicted in ImageView and TextView. Try removing that too.

Comment: `android:layout_below="@+id/textTop"` **this is wrong forma**t. it should be 
`android:layout_below="@id/textTop"`

Comment: @Shree Krishna I have the arrow image in res/drawable/image, if i remove it no images show up. I have removed the ImageView with id image, no changes, and corrected the layout_below. The screenshots might be misleading sorry I don't have another ImageView the second pic and xml code are the same.

Comment: @anaxin and which XML is this actually ? Is it single item or parent having ListView ? Why are you mixing them ?

Comment: I have this one content_xml where I have the listView and TextViews that I use while populating the listView. I added some code to show how I'm populating it. I don't know if it helps. The listview and textviews where working fine. Is there another approach I can take to get that image in each listview item bottom row? I mean I think my whole approach is wrong here, can it be embedded into the second textView somehow?

Comment: I solved this by separating ListView and TextViews+ImageView to different xmls. Also, as @Shree Krishna pointed out `android:layout_below="@+id/textTop"` was causing problems. Thank you all.

Comment: @anaxin just set first xml file to only listview & other xml file is set 2textview and image view then its bind with adapter.

Comment: @anaxin good to hear that bro.. I suggest you to add this as answer and accept, Or let us add it's founded solution, what will you prefer ?

Comment: Go ahead I'll accept. It was mainly your comments ;)

Comment: Thanks for saying so brother, Happy coding !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Don't mix up `ListView` and other elements like `TextView` and `ImageView` which should be in the single item layout. Because of it you are seeing multiple images in single list.

And another thing to be noticed is your `android:layout_below="@+id/textTop"` attribute is conflicted in `ImageView` and `TextView` as well, so I suggest you to fix that as well.

Rest of the codes are fine enough !!

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra ImageView and 2 extra TextViews in your layout file. These should be in the layout file of your list adapter and not in the layout containing listview itself. Try removing these extra views, that might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

remove all content in your list view like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="anaxin.newshellas.Feed"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_feed">
<ListView
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/feedView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="false" />
```

you don't need them